# Jest test doesnt wait for a saga to end

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, redux-saga

Jest for testing,
Redux-Saga

Let's say I have this saga:

```
export function* callCreateTemplate({payload}){
try{
  ...
  yield delay(1500)
  ...
}
```

Don't judge me for having this delay(1500) is related to the API.

Then, I have my test case in Jest where I call the saga with runSaga:

```
it('...'), async () => {
   ...
   await runSaga(...);
   expect(dispatchedActions).toHaveLength(3);
}
```

dispatchedActions is part of the mock and is an array with all the dispatched actions that the saga executes.

The thing is that, when I delete the delay(1500) inside the saga, the test case works fine, but when I execute the test with the delay(1500) the dispatched actions after the delay don't execute.

How can I make the test case to wait for the execution of the saga?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[runSaga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#runsagaoptions-saga-args) returns a [Task](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#task) object which has a `task.toPromise()` method. You should convert the task to promise so that you can use `async/await` to wait for the completion of the task.

Besides, you need to make sure the value of `timeout` argument for the [test](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout) case is greater than the milliseconds passed in the `delay` effect.

```
import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga';
import { delay, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* callCreateTemplate({ payload }) {
  yield delay(1500);
  yield put({ type: 'CREATE_TEMPLATE', payload });
}

describe('callCreateTemplate', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const dispatchedActions: any[] = [];
    await runSaga(
      {
        dispatch: (action) => dispatchedActions.push(action),
        getState: () => ({}),
      },
      callCreateTemplate,
      { payload: 'fake payload' },
    ).toPromise();
    expect(dispatchedActions).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(dispatchedActions).toEqual([{ type: 'CREATE_TEMPLATE', payload: 'fake payload' }]);
  }, 2000);
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/71787549/index.test.ts
  callCreateTemplate
    ✓ should pass (1508 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.118 s
```